# Can't set protobuf fields due to read-only attribute error

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, object-detection-api

I am trying to create an instance of [this proto template.](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/protos/image_resizer.proto) Compiled and imported, I run the following code:

```
from object_detection.protos import image_resizer_pb2

resizer = image_resizer_pb2.ImageResizer()
resizer.keep_aspect_ratio_resizer.min_dimension = 1536
resizer.keep_aspect_ratio_resizer.max_dimension = 1536
resizer.keep_aspect_ratio_resizer.pad_to_max_dimension = True
```

And get this error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-30cfb0c18c35> in <module>
      3 
      4 resizer = image_resizer_pb2.ImageResizer()
----> 5 resizer.keep_aspect_ratio_resizer.min_dimension = 1536
      6 resizer.keep_aspect_ratio_resizer.max_dimension = 1536
      7 resizer.keep_aspect_ratio_resizer.pad_to_max_dimension = True

AttributeError: 'KeepAspectRatioResizer' object attribute 'min_dimension' is read-only
```

Except nothing in the proto file even begins to suggest it should be read-only, or that a protobuf field being read-only is even *possible*? I've tried to copy the field values from the keep aspect ratio message instead, but that *also* throws the read-only error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your protobuf dependency might be out of date, try `pip3 install --upgrade protobuf`

Comment: That was it. Anaconda version is out of date; 3.14.0; upgrading to 3.15.8 let me create the message directly.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, it was possible to get around the inability to manually create a template by using the `object_detection.utils/config_utils` file and loading the image config I want to replicate from the model configuration file directly:

```
from object_detection.protos import image_resizer_pb2
from object_detection.utils import config_util as c

config =  c.get_configs_from_pipeline_file(r"C:\Users\Person\.keras\datasets\efficientdet_d7_coco17_tpu-32\pipeline.config")
image_config = c.get_image_resizer_config(config['model'])
print(image_config.ListFields())
```

```
[(<google.protobuf.descriptor.FieldDescriptor object at 0x000002446C225F40>, min_dimension: 1536
max_dimension: 1536
pad_to_max_dimension: true
)]
```

Thus sidestepping the issue with read-only attributes, though I still don't see how it was being interpreted as read-only to start with or how to address that normally.